# Grid with advance filtering on related tables

Tags: asp.net

I want to let the user to filter on a grid, but not to filter just on the data seen but also on related tables.

sample:

```
Users
-- Id
-- Name
UserDetails
-- UserId
-- Rating
```

I show only the 'Users' table and I want so the client can filter by the related table 'UserDetails' - so only a user with rating X will be shown or rating over Y, etc.

Is there any grid in the web so will support this type of filtering?

Comment: seems like you can query your data source and just update the grid server side‽ If that's not what you're looking for, please provide some more context.

Comment: Yes - The query need to be in the Server Side - But is there anything automatic for it? (Say the filtering of devexpress)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know devexpress. You might dig into their docs. But it seems easy to adjust your query and rebind the datasource.

Comment: devexpress don't have it - I searching for some component as devexpress so will do the job